# Where to put the PIT mutation testing history file?

Tags: java, git, jenkins, mutation-testing, pitest

Where do I put the PIT mutation testing history file so that a new Jenkins job picks it up? Because when I build on Jenkins, the job starts every time on an entirely new workspace without any previous analysis history, which results in a looooong analysis time. So I need to have the previous analysis history *of that specific branch* somewhere.

Do I put the PIT mutation testing history file in the project build directory:

```xml
            <historyInputFile>${project.build.directory}/pitest.history</historyInputFile>
            <historyOutputFile>${project.build.directory}/pitest.history</historyOutputFile>
```

and commit it to Git? Will I have to commit it every time I do an analysis? Won't that bloat the repository? It is a generated file, and it is generally bad practice to put generated files in Git, isn't it?.

How have other people done this?

I'm terribly ashamed for asking an opinion-based question, so I would really, really appreciate good comments that help to turn this into a more useful question.

Comment: Save it in a location all your jenkins nodes can reach, or otherwise copy it in from. Using an artifacts plugin in Jenkins is one method.

Comment: Artifacts! Yes! I can put it on our Artifactory server at the end of a job, and retrieve it from there at the start of a job. You, Sir, are a genius!